# Is OL3's growing DOM Node count a performance issue?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, nodes

I've noticed that OL3 creates additional DOM nodes with every zoom in and out or pan...
[ol3 growing dom nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwTP.png)

...evidenced in both locally-deployed versions and in the [official examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.0/examples/canvas-tiles.html).

Ol3, however, does *not* create new DOM nodes when a layer is made visible/not visible, and doesn't appear to create new DOM nodes when a new layer is added, so long as no zoom in/out or pan actions happen at the same time.

Tracking down the timing of DOM nodes added- sometimes- coincides with numerous 'image decode' events in the Chrome dev console.

Are there any causes for concern (performance worries) about an ever-growing DOM node count?  What would cause these growing node counts on zoom/pan, but not with a visible/new layer change?

Comment: Are you actually seeing a performance issue, or are you just asking if it _might_ be a problem?

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue yet, but I can't affect this trend so don't know what performance gain could be achieved.  As the number of map layers and pre/post compose events increase so does rate of node count growth.  When the nodes reach upwards of 5 digits, interaction with ol3 feels jerky.  By process of elimination, this pattern is the root of the issue.